# Sort the series data for every X-Axis in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, java, charts, highcharts

I need to sort the data of series from largest to smallest for every series.

[Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1uu7edpw/2/)

```
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [{
            y: 1}, {y: 2}, {y: 3}, {y: 4}, {y: 5
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [{
            y: 5}, {y: 4}, {y: 3}, {y: 2}, {y: 1
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [{
            y: 5}, {y: 2}, {y: 3}, {y: 4}, {y: 1
        }]
    }]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [sort function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). It can be applied like that:

```
series.forEach(function(name){
  name.data.sort(function (a,b) {
    if(a.y < b.y) {
      return 1;
    } else if (a.y > b.y) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
});
```

To make the code more understandable you can create a `series` variable and then sort it before calling the `highcharts` function. This is demonstrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/43xt8kqh/1/).

Comment: Tried this but it doesn't work. Pls refer the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1uu7edpw/5/. Don't how to refer the series

Comment: This sort the series on a whole which leads to wrongly assign the value to Category. For e.g. The value of 'Jane' and 'Joe' for Apple category is 5 and 5. But after sorting it is assigned to value 0.

Comment: My Expectation is, in http://jsfiddle.net/1uu7edpw/2/, Banana category should be displayed as {John:5, Joe:1, Jane: 1} as opposed to current format {Joe:1, Jane:1, John:5}.

Comment: This doesn't really fit the description of your original problem. You rather want to sort the data that gets displayed in each bar. I've looked into the Highcharts API and found no easy solution to your problem. I think you should create another question that would explain what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for reply