# Highcharts - How to sort data by name?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am currently working on a horizontal bar graph with Highcharts. I have 5 different categories `Low, Medium Low, Medium, Medium High and High` I would like to sort the data being returned from the graph by category name by descending order having `Low` be the starting point. For example, all `Low` data appears first in the graph, all `Medium Low`, all `Medium` appears next and so on.

I've done some research and it appears that the code below is what I need

```
              dataSorting: {
                enabled: true,
                matchByName: true
            },
```

but when applying this to HighCharts it did not affect my graph. Is this a feature that is provided in HighCharts? Is this something that is possible to do?

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/52pwy1tk/1/)

My code:

```
let data = [10, 31, 13, 19, 21, 50, 10]

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
  title: {
    text: "Bar Graph"
  },
  xAxis: {

  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    formatter: function() {
      return this.value + "%";
    },
    title: {
      text: '% of Total'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    reversed: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Low',
    color: '#0D6302',
    data: [data[0]],
    showInLegend: true,
  }, {
    name: 'Medium-Low',
    color: '#0B7070',
    data: [data[2]]
  }, {
    name: 'Medium',
    color: '#DC9603',
    data: [data[3]]
  },{
    name: 'Low',
    color: '#0D6302',
    data: [data[1]],
    showInLegend: false
  }, 
  {
    name: 'Medium-High',
    color: '#DD5F0C',
    data: [data[4]]
  }, {
    name: 'High',
    color: '#C50710',
    data: [data[5]]
  }]
});
```

---

Current look:

[image]

---

Desired look:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `index` feature to define the affecting the order of rendering.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9Lsvmpbh/

```
  series: [{
    name: 'Low',
    index: 4,
    color: '#0D6302',
    data: [data[0]],
    showInLegend: true,
  }, {
    name: 'Medium-Low',
    index: 3,
    color: '#0B7070',
    data: [data[2]]
  }, {
    name: 'Medium',
    index: 2,
    color: '#DC9603',
    data: [data[3]]
  },{
    name: 'Low',
    index: 5,
    color: '#0D6302',
    data: [data[1]],
    showInLegend: false
  }, 
  {
    name: 'Medium-High',
    index: 1,
    color: '#DD5F0C',
    data: [data[4]]
  }, {
    name: 'High',
    index: 0,
    color: '#C50710',
    data: [data[5]]
  }]
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.index

Answer (score 0):

You should reorder your series' objects. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39678141/highcharts-how-to-sort-xaxis-category-by-total), highchart doesn't have a property to sort automatically. You should insert first your `Low` series, then `Medium Low` etc. The thing you want to be the last one, you should put it first in the `series`.

Following this

```
    let data = [10, 31, 13, 19, 21, 50, 10]

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
  title: {
    text: "Bar Graph"
  },
  xAxis: {

  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    formatter: function() {
      return this.value + "%";
    },
    title: {
      text: '% of Total'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    reversed: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'sorted'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'High',
    color: '#C50710',
    data: [data[5]]

  }, {
    name: 'Medium-High',
    color: '#DD5F0C',
    data: [data[4]]

  }, {
    name: 'Medium',
    color: '#DC9603',
    data: [data[3]]
  },{
    name: 'Medium-Low',
    color: '#0B7070',
    data: [data[2]]

  }, 
  {
    name: 'Low',
    color: '#0D6302',
    data: [data[1]],
    showInLegend: false
  }, {
    name: 'Low',
    color: '#0D6302',
    data: [data[0]],
    showInLegend: true,
  }]
});
```

I got this result:

[image]