# How to arrange columns from High to Low in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, highcharts

I am trying to dynamically arrange columns from high to low based on column size in Highcharts. Right now it is showing unordered as shown in below image. One way I could do is I can short the data through SQL query when I am fetching from backend but I was wondering if there is a way I could do easier than that.

[image: Right now it is showing unordered as shown in below image.]

```
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'World\'s largest cities per 2014'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_proper_by_population">Wikipedia</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        labels: {
            rotation: -45,
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Population (millions)'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: 'Population in 2008: <b>{point.y:.1f} millions</b>'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Population',
        data: [
            ['Shanghai', 23.7],
            ['Lagos', 16.1],
            ['Istanbul', 14.2],
            ['Karachi', 14.0],
            ['Mumbai', 12.5],
            ['Moscow', 12.1],
            ['São Paulo', 25],
            ['Beijing', 4],
            ['Guangzhou', 11.1],
            ['Delhi', 11.1],
            ['Shenzhen', 2],
            ['Seoul', 10.4],
            ['Jakarta', 10.0],
            ['Kinshasa', 9.3],
            ['Tianjin', 2],
            ['Tokyo', 9.0],
            ['Cairo', 29],
            ['Dhaka', 8.9],
            ['Mexico City', 22],
            ['Lima', 8.9]
        ],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            rotation: -90,
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            align: 'right',
            format: '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
            y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Here is one example JSfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/5yrmnbzy/

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34565347/sort-the-series-data-for-every-x-axis-in-highcharts) looks like the same basic question (just with the series oriented on a different axis).

Comment: The general concept is that you should sort all data in the preprocessing and then init a chart. The Highcharts does not have build-in sorting solution, but you can post it in our [userVoice](https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api).